# How to fix date picker overlapping text in view?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I have a Modal, where there is a date picker followed by 2 buttons, however whenever I open the date-picker to select a date from the calender the buttons are hidden as follows:

[image]

Below is the code that I have written:

```
 <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        zIndex: 2,
      }}>
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}>
        <View
          style={
            width > 414
              ? {
                  backgroundColor: 'white',
                  height: '350px',
                  width: '350px',
                }
              : {
                  backgroundColor: 'white',
                  height: '280px',
                  width: '310px',
                }
          }>
          <Text
            style={{
              fontFamily: 'Roboto',
              fontWeight: 'bold',
              fontSize: 18,
              textAlign: 'center',
              padding: 20,
            }}>
            {name}
          </Text>
          <View
            style={{
              borderBottomColor: '#18D0E4',
              borderBottomWidth: 1,
            }}
          />
          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: 'row',
              justifyContent: 'center',
              marginTop: '5%',

              padding: 20,
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}>
            <View
              style={{justifyContent: 'space-evenly', flexDirection: 'row'}}>
              {reminder == 6 && toggle == 6 ? (
                <TouchableOpacity style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                  <Image
                    source={Images.circle}
                    style={{
                      height: 15,
                      width: 15,
                      marginTop: '2%',
                      paddingRight: '1%',
                    }}
                  />
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                      fontSize: 17,
                      color: '#000',
                      marginLeft: 5,
                    }}>
                    Set Different {'\n'}reminder
                  </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              ) : (
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}
                  onPress={() => reminderSet()}>
                  <Image
                    source={Images.circle_o}
                    style={{
                      height: 15,
                      width: 15,
                      marginTop: '2%',
                      paddingRight: '1%',
                    }}
                  />
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                      fontSize: 17,
                      marginLeft: 5,
                      color: '#000',
                    }}>
                    Set Different {'\n'}reminder
                  </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              )}
              {vaccinatedOn == 1 && toggle == 1 ? (
                <TouchableOpacity style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                  <Image
                    source={Images.circle}
                    style={{
                      height: 15,
                      width: 15,
                      marginTop: '2%',
                      // paddingRight: '1%',
                    }}
                  />
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                      fontSize: 17,
                      marginLeft: 5,
                      color: '#000',
                    }}>
                    Vaccinated on
                  </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              ) : (
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}
                  onPress={() => vaccinationSet()}>
                  <Image
                    source={Images.circle_o}
                    style={{
                      height: 15,
                      width: 15,
                      marginTop: '2%',
                      // paddingRight: '1%',
                    }}
                  />
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                      fontSize: 17,
                      marginLeft: 5,
                      color: '#000',
                    }}>
                    Vaccinated on
                  </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              )}
            </View>
          </View>
          <View
            style={{
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}>
            <DatePicker selected={date} onChange={(date) => setDate(date)} />
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          backgroundColor: '#fff',
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          width: '82%',
          position: 'absolute',
          top: '80%',
        }}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            borderTopColor: '#C0C0C0',
            borderTopWidth: 1,
            borderRightColor: '#C0C0C0',
            borderRightWidth: 1,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            padding: 10,
          }}
          onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
          <Text
            style={{
              fontFamily: 'Roboto',
              fontSize: 17,
              fontWeight: 'bold',
              color: '#000',
            }}>
            Cancel
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            borderTopColor: '#C0C0C0',
            borderTopWidth: 1,
            borderLeftColor: '#C0C0C0',
            borderLeftWidth: 1,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            padding: 10,
          }}
          onPress={() => SaveData(id)}>
          <Text
            style={{
              fontFamily: 'Roboto',
              fontSize: 17,
              fontWeight: 'bold',
              color: '#000',
            }}>
            OK
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
```

Kindly, let me know where am going wrong and how to resolve?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you have placed buttons container after the date picker container with the absolute property so it will render after it. Placed it before DatePicker container so it will not overlap